# Refresh/reload the content in Div using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to reload a div on click of a button. I do not want to reload the full page.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
    <input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Capture Again" class="disabled" />
    <input type="button" id="confirmNext"  value="Confirm & Proceed" class="disabled marginLeft50" />
</div>
```

On click of `<input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Capture Again">` Button a `<div id="list">....</div>` should reload without loading or refreshing full page.

Below is the Jquery which I tried, but not working:-

```
$("#getCameraSerialNumbers").click(function () {
    $("#step1Content").load();
});
```

Please suggest.

Here is the DIV on my page, which contains Pictures and Serial numbers of some products... Which will be coming from database 1st time on the Page Load. But Is User faces some issue he'll click tthe "Capture Again" button "`<input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Capture Again">`" which will load those information again.

The HTML Code of Div:-

```
<div id="step1Content" role="Step1ShowCameraCaptures" class="marginLeft">

<form>
    <h1>Camera Configuration</h1>
    <!-- Step 1.1 - Image Captures Confirmation-->
    <div id="list">
        <div>
            <p>
                <a id="pickheadImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="" href="">
                    <img alt="" id="pickheadImage" src="" width="250" height="200" />
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Pickhead Camera Serial No:</strong><br />
                <span id="pickheadImageDetails"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <a id="processingStationSideImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="" href="">
                    <img alt="" id="processingStationSideImage" src="" width="250" height="200" />
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Processing Station Top Camera Serial No:</strong><br />
                <span id="processingStationSideImageDetails"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <a id="processingStationTopImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="" href="">
                    <img alt="" id="processingStationTopImage" src="" width="250" height="200" />
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Processing Station Side Camera Serial No:</strong><br />
                <span id="processingStationTopImageDetails"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <a id="cardScanImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="" href="">
                    <img alt="" id="cardScanImage" src="" width="250" height="200" />
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Card Scan Camera Serial No:</strong><br />
                <span id="cardScanImageDetails"></span>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearall"></div>

    <div class="marginTop50">
        <p><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="optionYes" />Yes, the infomation captured is correct.</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="optionNo" />No, Please capture again.</p>
    </div>
    <div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
        <input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Capture Again" class="disabled" />
        <input type="button" id="confirmNext"  value="Confirm & Proceed" class="disabled marginLeft50" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Now on click of `<input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Capture Again" class="disabled" />` button, the information which is in `<div id="list">... </div>`  should be loaded again.

Please let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: There's not nearly enough detail here. Where are you trying to get content from? What code have you got to do that? Are there any errors? Why does it 'not work'?

Comment: What do you exactly want to reload? Would you need to call the database?

Comment: What is inside #step1Content and what you want it to be after clicking the button?

Comment: The question is how do you firstly fill DIV #list content?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I always use this, works perfect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
        $('#ideal_form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                var post_url = form.attr('action');
                var post_data = form.serialize();
                $('#loader3', form).html('<img src="../../images/ajax-loader.gif" />       Please wait...');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: post_url, 
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $(form).fadeOut(800, function(){
                            form.html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);

                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
         });
```

Comment: I think you can also remove the `delay` since it, as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), delays _subsequent_ calls.

Comment: Oh Yes, its Just a nice effect! ;)

Comment: `$('#loader3', form);` contains form ? can i remove this? because i am using change methed not submit.

Comment: 151291 yes, its the ID of my form, change it as your needs.

Comment: `form` is a wrapped in jquery so why did you do  `$(form).fadeOut(800, function(){`

Answer (score 151):

```
$("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
```

Always take note of the space just before the **second** **#** sign, otherwise the above code will return the whole page nested inside you intended DIV. Always put space.

Comment: This nests a #mydiv in a #mydiv for every call to load. The correct version is provided by Juan.

Comment: This is not AJAX as the questions says.

Comment: It's not necessarily AJAX, but delivers the expected user experience

Comment: Is it possible to include parameters in the uri? For example:             `$("#relation-body").load(location.href+" #relation-body?organization_id="+item.id);`

Comment: This would affect jquery calls as it creates dynamic elements on the DOM, jquery fails. So make use of `on` event in jquery instead of directly accessing the element inside this div

Comment: worth noting that any jquery $(document).ready functions that apply to elements within that div will not get triggered by this reload.

Comment: is will create #mydiv inside parent #mydiv. so if you are using bootstrap then it will affect shchema.

Answer (score 83):

```
$("#myDiv").load(location.href+" #myDiv>*","");
```

Comment: Please provide explanations along your answer, it will help others understand why you think it is a good answer to the question.

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 To be honest, Peca answered a couple of months after Juan :)

Comment: @Juan: could you please explain what it does exactly. thanks

Comment: How would I adjust this to also reload all children?

Comment: can i use class insted of id ?

Comment: I am finding that this implementation also results in the nesting problem.

Answer (score 18):

When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `location.href`, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with `divId`. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID (`divId`) of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

> $("#divId").load(location.href + " #divId>*", "");

hope this may help someone to understand

Answer (score 9):

While you haven't provided enough information to actually indicate WHERE you should be pulling data from, you do need to pull it from somewhere.  You can specify the URL in load, as well as define data parameters or a callback function.

```
$("#getCameraSerialNumbers").click(function () {
    $("#step1Content").load('YourUrl');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to achieve my condition. :)

Answer (score 7):

What you want is to load the data again but not reload the div.

You need to make an Ajax query to get data from the server and fill the DIV.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

html code

```
 <div id="refresh">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="button" id="click" />
 </div>
```

jQuery code

```
 <script>
    $('#click').click(function(){
    var div=$('#refresh').html();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {param1: 'value1'},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
if(data.success=='ok'){
        $('#refresh').html(div);
}else{
// show errors.
}
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
    });

</script>
```

php page code path=/path/to/file.php

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $done=true;
   if($done){
       echo json_encode(['success'=>'ok']);
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the source from where you're loading the data.

For Example:

```
$("#step1Content").load("yourpage.html");
```

Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is old, but you can declare the Ajax as a variable, then use a function to call the variable on the desired content. Keep in mind you are calling what you have in the Ajax if you want a different elements from the Ajax you need to specify it.

Example:

```
Var infogen = $.ajax({'your query')};

$("#refresh").click(function(){
  infogen;
  console.log("to verify");
});
```

Hope helps

if not try:

```
$("#refresh").click(function(){
      loca.tion.reload();
      console.log("to verify");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("#categoryTable").load(window.location + " #categoryTable");
```

Here i mentioned **Table Id** where i loading data and after delete. i am calling this code and it will refresh data without whole **Page** load.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was something like this:

```
$('#x').html($('#x').html())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pageRefresh = 5000; //5 s
    setInterval(function() {
        refresh();
    }, pageRefresh);
});

// Functions

function refresh() {
    $('#div1').load(location.href + " #div1");
    $('#div2').load(location.href + " #div2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way we pass the route name to jquery

```
var url = ' {{ route ("admin.task.delete", ":id") }}'; 
url = url.replace(':id',id);
```

then use the url variable like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
```

and the rest of the ajax