# div reload not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a shopping cart page. I am using ajax function to add products to cart. so my page will not refresh. But after added to cart , i need to display you have n number of items in your cat. It is working fine if i refresh my page. i need to do that without refrsh my page
i have write this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addtocartbutton").click(function(){


   $("#cartdiv").refresh();


  });
});
</script>
```

but not refrshing that div. please helm me friends

Comment: Where is your ajax call?

Comment: `you have n number of items in your cat` Poor kitten!

Answer (score 0):

Cool, so the ideal way to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is:

Within `sucess` function you update your page or div.

Also for the `load` issue look in here * [Refresh/reload the content in Div using jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)

Hope this gives you enough to rectify the ajax `:)` and reload the information in `div`

**Sample code**

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) like,

```
$("#cartdiv").load('page.php');
```