# Refresh a HTML5 div while page is resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to refresh a div only while resizing the html page without setting a timer?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Fixed grammar and made the question a bit more understandable.

Also, perhaps describe exactly what you mean by 'refresh'. Provide some code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window resize event like

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
   $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
});
```

Comment: I used this function only. want to refresh the particular div (<div class="testdiv"></div> only with out setting the timer.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following module, to perform action on window resize**

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    // add actions needed
});
```

[Resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

---

**To refresh div**

```
$("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
```

[source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26414078/2134604]