# Is there a way to refresh options of select tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

newbie here.
I am writing a code with these functions 
1. form for adding a new product 
2.appending this new product's name to a select element as one of its options 
3.select the newly appended product name to display it on a separate form.

I already have this working, but there is one problem.
when I try to add a new product and select this newly added product from the list it doesn't display the data on the input boxes inside the separate form.

but when i refresh the whole page. it works perfectly. is there any other  way to make it work other than refreshing the whole page?

I was thinking if is it possible to refresh only the select tag.

below is my code:

**Add new product form:**

```
 <div id='bgw' style='background:#fff; height:80%; top:7%;left:2%; width:90%;position:absolute;margin;text-align:center;padding:20px; border-radius:10px;'>     
                        <label style='font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f01;'>Add New Product to List</label><br><br><br>
                        <table style='margin-left:30px;'>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Product Name</label></td>
                                <td><label>Product Category</label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" class="input" id="prod_name" style='width:250px;' /></td>    
                                <td>
                                    <select id = "prod_category" style="font-family:verdana; width:250px; height:34px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
                                          <option value="">---</option>
                                          <optgroup label="Apparel">
                                             <option value="Footwear">Footwear</option>
                                             <option value="Underwear">Underwear</option>
                                             <option value="Outerwear">Outerwear</option>
                                             <option value="Cloth">Cloth</option>
                                             <option value="Jewelry">Jewelry</option>
                                             <option value="Headwear">Headwear</option>
                                             <option value="Eyewear">Eyewear</option>
                                             <option value="Legwear">Legwear</option>
                                             <option value="Blanket">Blanket</option>
                                             <option value="Carpet">Carpet</option>
                                             <option value="Sport Series">Sport Series</option>
                                          </optgroup>

                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Unit</label></td>
                                <td><label>PO Number</label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="prod_unit" style="width:250px;height:34px;" class="input">
                                        <option value="">---</option>
                                        <option value="Piece/s">Piece/s</option>
                                        <option value="Roll/s">Roll/s</option>
                                        <option value="Set/s">Set/s</option>
                                        <option value="Pair/s">Pair/s</option>
                                        <option value="Box/es">Box/es</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <td><input type="text"  class="input" id="prod_po" style="width:250px;"/></td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Brand</label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text"  class="input" id="prod_brand" style="width:250px;"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td><label>Color/Material/Finish</label></td>
                                <td><label>Technical Specifications/Rating</label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" id='prod_color' style="border:1px solid #000000;" ></textarea></td>
                                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" id='prod_spec' style="border:1px solid #000000;" ></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td><label>Shipping Mark</label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" id='prod_ship' style="border:1px solid #000000;"></textarea></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='button' id='cancel_prod' value='Cancel' style='width:100px;height:30px;border:none;border-radius:5px;background:#ff6f01;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;cursor:hand;cursor:pointer'> 
                                    <input type='button' id='save_prod' value='Save Product' style='width:150px;height:30px;border:none;border-radius:5px;background:#ff6f01;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;cursor:hand;cursor:pointer'>

                                </td>
                            </tr>                           
                        </table>

                    </div>
```

**AJAX Script for adding products:**

```
 $.ajax({
        url     :   'ajaxrequests.php',
        type    :   'POST',
        async   :   false,
        data    :   {
                prodsave    : 1,
                compid : compid,
                pname  : prodname,
                pcat   : prodcat,
                punit  : produnit,
                ppo    : prodpo,
                pbrand : prodbrand,
                pcmf   : prodcmf,
                ptech  : prodtech,
                pship  : prodship
                },
        success: function(result){
                if (result == 0) {
                    $('.name_of_product').each(function(){
                        var new_prod = $('#prod_name').val();
                        $(this).append('<option value="'+new_prod+ '">'+new_prod+'</option>');
                    })
                    alert('New Product details has been saved!');
                    $('#prod_name').val("");
                    $('#prod_category').val("");
                    $('#prod_po').val("");
                    $('#prod_brand').val("");
                    $('#prod_unit').val("")
                    $('#compid').val("");
                    $('#prod_color').val("");
                    $('#prod_spec').val("");
                    $('#prod_ship').val("");
                    $('#bgw').hide(500);
                    $('#bgb').hide(500);
                }else if(result == 1){
                    alert('There was a problem saving the product details. Pelase try again later.');
                }else if (result == 2) {
                    alert("Please fill in all fields");
                }else if(result == 3){
                    alert("Product Name already exists! Please press cancel and select from the list or if you are adding a new product, give the product a different name.");
                }   
            }
    });
```

**ajaxrequests.php**

```
 include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['prodsave'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['pname']) && !empty($_POST['pcat']) && !empty($_POST['ppo']) && !empty($_POST['pbrand']) && !empty($_POST['pcmf'])&& !empty($_POST['ptech']) && !empty($_POST['pship'])){
        $showid = $_POST['compid'];
        $pname = $_POST['pname'];
        $pcat = $_POST['pcat'];
        $ppo = $_POST['ppo'];
        $pbrand = $_POST['pbrand'];
        $pcmf = $_POST['pcmf'];
        $ptech = $_POST['ptech'];
        $pship = $_POST['pship'];
        $punit = $_POST['punit'];

        $qry = $handler->prepare("SELECT * From product_list WHERE plist_name = ? AND plist_compid = ? ");
        $qry->execute(array($pname,$showid));
        $row = $qry->rowCount();

        if ($row >=1) {
                echo 3;
            }else{
            $qry = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO product_list (plist_compid, plist_name, plist_category, plist_unit, plist_po, plist_brand, plist_cmf, plist_spec, plist_ship) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $qry->execute(array($showid, $pname, $pcat, $punit, $ppo, $pbrand, $pcmf, $ptech, $pship));

                if ($qry) {
                    echo 0;
                }else{
                    echo 1;
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo 2;
        }
        exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['psearch'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['product']) && !empty($_POST['compid'])) {
        $showprod = $_POST['product'];
        $showid = $_POST['compid'];
        $qry = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE plist_name = ? AND plist_compid = ?");
        $qry->execute(array($showprod,$showid));
        $rows = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("Content-type: text/x-json");
        echo json_encode($rows);
        exit();
    }
}
```

**JQUERY for displaying data on separate form*

```
$('#page3_inside').on('change','.name_of_product', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var prodname = $(this).val();
var cid = $('#compid').val();  // not found this in html

// should use this to find parent for current element, 
// and this is the main part(to find only current match element)
var $this = $(this).closest('tr'); 

$.ajax({
url : 'ajaxrequests.php',
type : 'POST',
datatype : 'JSON',
data : {
        psearch : 1,
        product : prodname,
        compid : cid
    },
success : function(show){

   // using $this as this would refer to previous context,
   // and find the sibling element only
   // Here you need to find element to attach the data
   // i could't find the match id in your html snippet
   // try this first
    $this.find('.name_of_product').val(show.plist_name);
    $this.find('.product_category').val(show.plist_category);
    $this.find('.po').val(show.plist_po);
    $this.find('.brand').val(show.plist_brand);
    $this.find('.unit').val(show.plist_unit);
    }
});                 
});
```

any help would be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: You can refresh without reloading using AJAX.

Comment: Sure it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax