# How can I add a parameter to my url, without reload the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

I have this url `http://localhost:1234/pag1`

I want to be like below when I click on the div:

```
 http://localhost:1234/pag1?fare=standar
```

and I have an onclick event function:

```
 <div id="" onclick="addUrl();"> </div>
```

And the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addUrl() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.location.hash = '?fare=standar';
};
    </script>
```

This give me this result:

```
http://localhost:1234/pag1#?fare=standar
```

And I don't Know how to remove the (#). I only need to add the parameter to the url, without refresh the page.

Suggest me! Thank's.

Comment: on clicking the div do you wnat to reload the page with the new url?

Comment: On clicking the div I want tho add the new parameter to the actual url, without reload the page.

Comment: then you need to strore the url in  a variable. You can not show it in url.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `window.history.pushState( {} , '', '?fare=standar' );`

This should update the url without refresh.

You can also do a bit of reseach on pushState as the implementation can differ.

Comment: Just tested that method on stackoferflow page and it works.
Type the method in console and see the result

Comment: Please mark the answer if it's the correct one :)
Thanks

Comment: Yes, your answer works correctly, thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1):

window.location.hash always put "#" in url

you can use to push paramter in url by using this function

```
function setGetParameter(paramName, paramValue)
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf(paramName + "=") >= 0)
    {
        var prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(paramName));
        var suffix = url.substring(url.indexOf(paramName));
        suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("=") + 1);
        suffix = (suffix.indexOf("&") >= 0) ? suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("&")) : "";
        url = prefix + paramName + "=" + paramValue + suffix;
    }
    else
    {
    if (url.indexOf("?") < 0)
        url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    else
        url += "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

i hope this will helpful to you

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but is too long code, I get the solution in one line ;-D

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

HTML

```
<div onclick="addUrl()"> </div>
```

Javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addUrl() {
    var url = window.history.pushState( {} , '', '?fare=standar' );
  </script>
```

> **Quick Explanation :** When user clicks on div, URL will update without refreshing the page.

Hope this will work for you,
thank you :-).

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var myURL = document.location;
document.location = myURL + "?a=parameter";
```

Or

```
location.hash = 'a=parameter'
```

Or without reloading the page

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "new url");
```

Or without reloading the page

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/another-new-url");
```

Comment: I don't want to reload the page.

Answer (score -3):

Why dont you use jQuery? I prepared sample like here in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2526328/):

```
$("#clickableDiv").click(function(){
  var url = "http://localhost:1234/pag1";
  var parameter = "fare=standar";
  $("#AppendUrl").text(url+ "?" + parameter);  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you add the url to a <p>, I need to add this to URL without reload the page.

Comment: I don't understand you. Did you mean Ajax ? Something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax