# how to refresh select box without reloading the whole form in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a form in a modal where i add new fields to the select box and would like to refresh the select box such that the new options are added to it. And this without reloading the entire page . Can someone please tell me if this is possible or not and if it is how do i go about it.

Comment: is it simple select dropdown or some plugin you are using

Comment: `$("form")[0].reset();`?

Comment: Hi, Could you pls jsFiddle or something ?

Comment: **Step 1**: Make API call and get new options. **Step 2**: Update selectbox with new options

Comment: Hey it is possible to reload select box however I would like to know what have you tried so far. If you have any code, please share.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: `$("#dropdownlist").empty();`

Comment: Let us see at least the select and the new options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#test").append($('<option>', {value: 2,text: 'Two'}));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
          <option value="1">One</option>
 </select>
```

Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: This is closest to what i want. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

**First** if you are using **jQuery** this is simple like:

```
$("#dropdownlist").empty();
```

**Another** way can be:

```
for(i = dropdownlist.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
   dropdownlist.remove(i);
}
```

**Another** simplest way can be:

```
document.getElementById("dropdownlist").innerHTML = "";
```

Now if you want to repopulate it. You can append the options with jQuery. If you have single value you can achieve it like:

```
$('#dropdownlist').append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'New option'
}));
```

And if it's a collection. you need to loop over it like the following snippet:

```
 $.each(newOptions, function (i, val) {
        $('#dropdownlist').append($('<option>', { 
            value: val.value,
            text : val.text 
        }));
    });
```