# Impossible to call several times java bean function with remotecommand

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

I want to simply print a message  with a java bean method every time I click on a header.

So this is what I tried to do :

I have a java bean class (with annotation "Test") in which I have the method I will associate to my remoteCommand tag :

```
public void printSomething(){
     System.out.println("Something");
}
```

I've created a form tag containing my remoteCommand tag in my xhtml file :

```
<h:form id="form1">
        <p:remoteCommand name="print"
            actionListener="#{Test.printSomething}"/>
</h:form>
```

And this is my javascript :

```
<script>
    $('th').on('click', function() {
        alert("Hi");
        print();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is my function is only called once when I click for the first time in a header ("Something" is printed on my terminal) . If I try to click on another header just after, it doesn't react. The alert message in my javascript doesn't appear after the first click.

Do you know why and how I can fix it ?

**Update 1** : I tried with different selectors :

first try with : `$('th').click(function(){ ...`// same result
second try with : `$('th').bind('click', function() { ...` // same result

I don't think this is a JS problem, I assume it must be something with primefaces but I still didn't find how to solve it.

**Update 2** : It's actually working everytime I refresh the page with F5 after a click but this is not what I want.

**Update 3** : Still didn't find how to do it but I was wondering if I can "manually" refresh with a jquery function (not the entire page) ?

I want to use `load()` function, I want to do something like this :

```
<script>
    $('th').on('click', function() {
        alert("Hi");
        print();
        $("#form1").load(location.href + " #form1");
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working, is it something to do with the syntax ? I searched here : [Refresh/reload the content in Div using jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: So it work if you don't do a 'print()' in the javascript function? You then always get an alert?

Comment: Yes I always get the message of the alert if I delete the call of the function print().