# Only show new content of PHP array with jQuery request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on improving my chat script using jQuery to display and autoscroll the messages. It already works pretty good, but I want to get rid of the 'refresh' effect when replacing the 'div' with updated content from the JSON object, which gets encoded from a PHP array containing the messages with every jQuery request.

How can I achieve this?

This is what works now for me:

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
      $("a").click(function(){
        $("div").empty(); // removing this will get rid of the 'refresh' effect, but it endlessly appends the message log

        $.getJSON('ajax.php', function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(field + "<br>");
          });
          $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
        });
      });
    });

    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("refreshB")[0].click();
    };

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(refresh, 10000);

    function refresh() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("refreshB")[0].click();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="refreshB"></a>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont see PHP Code

Comment: i assume then that you are retreiving the full conversation each time? I would recommend splitting the entries by time, and getting only the new ones.. but that means changing substantial part of the code. The alternative is comparing, which will make your code even slower

Comment: Your PHP will have to decide what is "new" content that needs to be sent to the browser.  As it is currently designed, your JS has no idea what's old and what's new; it simply replaces everything in the chat window with whatever the PHP sends along

Comment: smells like a homework assignment

Comment: Simply move the `$('div').empty()` to the xhr success callback, that eliminates the time between request and response and will look like an instant repaint

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: How to compare the entries?

Comment: @giorgio Where is the xhr success callback?

Comment: The `function(data) { ... }` part, which will get called when the ajax (=xhr) response is received

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you must get only new rows from db.

add new column to table (for example `readed`) then every time update this column to know which data is new

and you won't need this `$("div").empty();`