# Strange behaviour with jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery's load function to updated a div inside my jsp. However the issue is, even if I give the wrong div id the correct div gets updated but if I give the correct div id , it doesn't work.

Inside my jsp:

`<div id="markers" class="height-400"></div>`

Inside Js:

`$("#marker").load(location.href + " #marker>*", ""); //works (notice marker instead of markers)`

`$("#markers").load(location.href + " #markers>*", ""); // Doesn't work`

Can someone please help me understand what's going on here.
Referring to this post [Refresh/reload the content in Div using jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code without the double quotes after your CLASS/ID.

`$("#markers").load(location.href + " #markers>*");`