# div element hides when load() function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm working on making ordering by some criterias(e.g. by price, by author) on my jsp page. And using ajax to reload content of div when new sorting option is selected. But when reload function is called, it just hides div on web page. 
 I've checked out, that **there are** books in session scope needed to be shown and Jquery is included correctly. 
 This is html for choosing criterias to sort by:

```
  <select>
        <option id="default">Default</option>
        <option id="price">By price</option>
        <option id="author">By author</option>
  </select>
```

And here is a code for processing *click* events for **select** element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
            let sortAttr = $('option:selected').attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                // passing data to servlet
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/sort',
                type: 'GET',
                // sort criteria
                data: ({sort: sortAttr}),
                // div needed to be reloaded
                success: function () {
                    $('#mydiv').load(' #mydiv');
                }
            });
        })
    });
})
```

And code on jsp page for the *div* needed to be reloaded:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <c:forEach var="book" items="${sessionScope.books}">
       <div class="col-4"><a href="/home?command=book_details&isbn=${book.ISBN}">
           <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${book.base64Image}">
           <h4>${book.title}</h4>
           <p>${book.price}$</p>
        </a></div>
   </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

**EDIT**

Finally, I found out what's happenning. The important thing to notice(especially for me) in `.load()` function is that whenever we call this function, it actually *not just refreshes div content with new data*, but makes request to the provided url and on *that* page(which url we provided) looks for the `div` selector, gets it's content and then goes back and inserts *that* content in current `div`. 
**Notice**, that If we don't write url, `.load()` function will make request to *current* page (correct me please, If I'm mistaken).

Hope that will help somebody!

Comment: Hi, why you need ajax here ? are you changing something inside your `DOM` from server ? Also , what you expect this - > `$('#mydiv').load(' #mydiv');` to do ?

Comment: Hi! Yes, It's a bit strange, but I didn't find a solution how to do it in DOM. I'm sorting elements which are stored in HttpSession. If I had an ability, I would sort them inside DOM. And here `$('#mydiv').load(' #mydiv');` I thried to reload div with old data, once new data is recieved from server

Comment: So inside your servlet you are setting new value in session .. why not return that `list` as json form and build that htmls inside your `ajax success` ? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/10606400) answer . Onces you tried that let me know if you get any errors .

Comment: Also, if you need to be your response to be reloaded to show new content then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax) should work .

Comment: I'm using JSTL on jsp page, so it is more convenient for me to put an object to session, otherwise, I have to rebuild some logic of my application. Unfortunatelly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax) link didn't solve the issue

Comment: Did you tried like this : `$("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");` ?

Comment: Yes, sure. I've tried it. I don't know what to do... I'm struggling with it 2 days...

Comment: Can you show server page code ? I will replicate this on my end

Comment: It is 200. But I don't understand why almost similar code works fine on other pages, and not here...

Comment: why are you doing `$('#mydiv').load(' #mydiv');`? Why is the sort code not returning the new content?

Comment: Using  this peace of code `$('#mydiv').load(' #mydiv');` I'm trying to reload div

Comment: Thanks! The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/10606400) you provided was very useful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to fix the typo in your code. Having space at the beginning of JQuery identifier won't find the required element.

Change this: `$('#mydiv').load(' #mydiv');`
To this: `$('#mydiv').load('#mydiv');`

Also, I think you're using it the wrong way.

Check the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I've removed estra space, as you said and that didn' fix the problem. And when I used `$('#mydiv').load()`, I got *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined*

Comment: Have you checked the documentation about how it works? Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25373840/10743722) would be helpful too.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the documentation, changed code to `$('#mydiv').load('#mydiv');`, but this still haven't solved the problem.  And what do you mean by saying `Also, I think you're using it the wrong way`?

Comment: You need to provide a `url` to `.load` - it looks like you want `$("#mydiv").load(url + " #mydiv")`

Comment: I have already tried it, but unsuccessfully. The thing is, that on other jsp this works fine. What is surprising, is that when .load() is called, *mydiv* content disappears

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Finally, I finished struggling with it by making myself fully  understand documentation

Answer (score 0):

How about

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $('select').on("change", function() { // when the select changes
    let sortAttr = $('option:selected', this).map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('id')
    }).get(); // get an array of selected IDs
    if (sortArrr.length > 0) {
      $('#mydiv').load('http://localhost:8080/sort?sort=' + 
        sortAttr.join(',') + // make a comma delimited string
        ' #mydiv'); // copy myDiv from the result
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Javscript... Can you explain a little bit what's going on here?

Comment: @Donny I have modified a little (why ajax if nothing selected) and added comments

Comment: Sorry, that didn't figured the problem out. But, thanks for explanation.

Comment: Your server needs to handle a comma separated list of IDs instead of what you do now

Comment: Okey, let it be. But the problem is that *mydiv* element hides at all after load function is called

Comment: Right click on the div and click inspect and see why. Perhaps it is empty or your JSP gives error

Comment: I've inspected the code in devTools, and noticed, that the is *still* presents old data, and div is not shown

Comment: And in the network tab calls the jsp correctly?

Comment: I told you incorrect information about whether data is present in mydiv on *elements* tab. So, no, there is no data in div

Comment: So look in the network tab to see if the server process returns anything

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was, that I didn't understand documentation fully. The important thing to notice(especially for me) was that when we call function .load(), it actually not just refreshes div content, but makes request to the provided url and on that page looks for the div, gets div content and then goes back and inserts that content in current div