# How to remove deleted array ids from table on ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with checkbox delete all option, it works fine delete items but cant remove that deleted items from the table on ajax response.

**How can I remove deleted multiple ids from tables on ajax response ?**

I have searched all site but there isnt a real solution for this, I tried all best answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135348/12232340) and more, but none of them are the correct answer.

Note: I can remove one deleted row with `$("#"+id).closest('tr').remove();` but cant delete multiple.

Best solution I found is `location.reload();`page, but if reloding page then dont need ajax.

This my ajax :

```
$(document).on('click','[data-bs-target="#deleteAll"]',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var del = new Array();
   $("input[name='del[]']:checked").each(function(){
     del.push($(this).val());
   });
   var valid = false;
   if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete this User ? ")){
      $.ajax({
      url:"modules/mod_users.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{del:del},
      dataType:"JSON",
         success:function(data){
           location.reload();
           valid = true;
         }
      });
   } else {
      return null;
   }
});
```

And php part :

```
if(isset($_POST['del'])) { 
  
  $error = '';

   $deleteAll = implode(', ', $_POST['del']);
   
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (' . $deleteAll . ')'); 
   $stmt->execute();
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
      @unlink('../images/avatars/' . $row["img"]);
   }
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN (' . $deleteAll . ')');
   $stmt->execute(); 
   if ($stmt) { 
      $error .= "Deleted.";
   }else{
      $error .= "Opps something went wrong.";
   }

echo json_encode($error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to delete all checked rows after ajax response?

If you do this

```
$("input[name='del[]']:checked").each(function(){
   del.push($(this).val());
});
```

you can do this in ajax response too

```
...
success:function(data){
  $("input[name='del[]']:checked").each(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });

  valid = true;
}
...
```