# Reload without Refreshing In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I am making a private webpage game in which you identify the color by only RGB displayed to you and I want to add "Score" system but I can't because I am using:
`function CR(){ window.location.reload(false) }`
which refreshes the whole page can someone show me how to make a part of the webpage refreshing without effecting everything?

Comment: is there any reason not to use spa like react or vuejs ??? you can update the dom element if you only want to update specific element.

Answer (score 0):

at first you should google it.

if you need get your data from backend,  you should use ajax.
[Refresh/reload the content in Div using jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)
[ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

if you don't need backend and you wanna change element value , so get your element by jQuery or JavaScript and set your value

```
$('#idTxt').val('new value');
```

Comment: I am trying not to go off my programming courses as we are still learning the frontend and not the backend and I tried google it failed me alot

Comment: well , if you don't need backend it so easier . you can get your element by jQuery or JavaScript and set your value.

don't forget , google and stackoverflow can be the best teacher to you